# Automatic Word Doc Completion from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, automation, ms-word

I'm after some advice, and certainly open to other suggestions on how to achieve what I'm trying to do here, so feel free to suggest alternatives.

I'm trying to build a quote document where we can automatically populate some fields (they will be product specifications) based on selecting an option in a list box. So far I've created my Drop Down List and populated with 2 options. I've then created 4 'specifications' I want to fill out and created a Content Control for each one.

What I'm trying to do at the moment is populate these content controls from an Excel sheet, where the different List Box items are titles of Sheets, and the specifications are in a column of each sheet.

```
Sub chillerdatafromexcel()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlbook As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\chris.garratt\Documents\Chiller Options.xlsx")
'Set xlbook.Sheets = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Chiller Supplier")
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("MaxCoolingPwr").Item(1).PlaceholderText = xlbook.Sheets(ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Chiller Supplier").Item(1).Range).Cells(2, 2)

    End Sub
```

[Word example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hELYv.png)
[Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx1Rj.png)

Any ideas welcome. I haven't done any text based coding / scripting for a long time, so feel free to dumb it down.

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Comment: The feature you are looking for is called "Mail Merge". It was originally created for mass mailing but you can use it for anything. You can use Excel cells or even a database as the source of the data. It will make a separate word doc for each record in a database, for example. It's amazing. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3

Comment: «The feature you are looking for is called "Mail Merge"» Not if the OP wants to select items from a dropdown in a Word document it isn't!

Answer (score 0):

See:

- http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16330-how-import-list-excel-into-drop-down.html#post46287

Others you might find useful include:

*Dependent Dropdown Content Controls*

- http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/24661-help-cascading-dropdown-list.html#post77762

*Hierarchical Dropdown Content Controls*

- http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/29617-creating-reducing-drop-down-list.html#post94603

*Dependent Text Content Controls*

- http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16498-multiple-entries-dropdown-lists.html#post46903
- http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16498-multiple-entries-dropdown-lists-5.html#post120392

*Content Control & Formfield Conditional Formatting*

- http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16505-change-color-according-dropdown-selection.html#post47254

*Creating and Tallying Mutually-exclusive Checkbox Content Controls*

- http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-tables/12335-assigning-values-content-control-checkboxes-calculating-results.html#post33489
- http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-tables/33248-content-control-checkbox-calculations.html#post107008

*Adding a new row to a table in a document with Content Controls:*

- http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/27809-code-add-new-row-table.html#post87989
- http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/13955-macro-add-row-table-word-form.html#post38461
- https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43603-multiple-dependent-dropdown-lists-table-add-new.html#post145675

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input. macropod, I'm sure those links will come in very helpful as I continue with this project.

I spent some time working on this yesterday before the replies came in, and I did manage to crack it (It's amazing what walking away and coming back with a fresh pair of eyes will do).

In the end, I settled on this:

```
Sub chillerdatafromexcel()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsheet As Excel.Sheets
Dim X As Integer
Dim ChillerOpt As String
Dim Offset As Integer

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ActiveDocument.Path & "\Chiller Options.xlsx")
    Offset = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Chiller Supplier").Count
    ChillerOpt = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Chiller Supplier").Item(1).Range


    For X = (Offset + 1) To (Offset + 4)

        ThisDocument.ContentControls(X).Range = xlbook.Sheets(ChillerOpt).Cells(X, 2)

    Next X

    xlbook.Close
    xlApp.Quit

End Sub
```

I have a few extra variables in there which will be relevant when I use this function in the context of a larger document. I was going for keeping it as flexible as possible. Avoiding hard coding. I have 4 cells in the spreadsheet I want to pull in, hence the X range.

Thanks for your help.

Chris